# Two-parametric transformation of Box-Cox vs Yeo–Johnson transformation

Tags: statistics, preprocessing, normalization

I choose which transformation to use for my data (data contains both positive and negative values).
Wikipedia says the following:

The Yeo – Johnson transformation allows also for zero and negative values of y (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform).

However, the two-parameter Box-Cox transformation also allows you to work with negative values:
[image]

When should I use the two-parameter box-cox transformation and when should I use the Yeo – Johnson transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box-Cox transformation cannot work with negative values. You can try feeding negative values to the box-cox transformation and it will give you an error.

Comment: But the two-parameter box-cox equation works for $y >= -\lambda_2$. Why then is there a two-parameter equation if one-parameter equation works with positive values?

Comment: Why is this $\lambda_2$ shift necessary?

Comment: There are 2 formulas of Box Cox, one for positive values and another for negative values. Currently sklearn only supports formula for positive values AFAIK. Check the official doc here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-transformer